# How can I compress many PDF Files into a single 7z using LZMA in JAVA

Tags: java, compression, zip, lzma

I'm trying to Zip many PDF files (representing tne same report containing same images and titles. Only some numbers differ from a PDF to another ) into a single "7z" (or any other extention) file using LZMA.

I'm using the java lzma SDK (which functions with only one file and creates only one result file).

Notice that I tried to compress my PDFs (60 files) with 7-zip, and the size (of all files ) decreased from 133Mo to 1,7Mo. I want to implement this on Java.

Thank you very much  for help.

Answer (score 1):

Does it *have* to be `7z`? What about a regular-ol' `zip`? [TrueZip](http://java.net/projects/truezip) is **excellent** for this.

Comment: Thanks for Help Matt Ball :) 
No it's not necessary to be 7z.. I'm only looking for a solution to send all my PDFs into one MAIL (10 Mo maximum size)

I'll try your solution and come back with my results ^^ !

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The LZMA library [LZMA-java](https://github.com/jponge/lzma-java) can create lzma files.  If you combine this with [TarArchiveOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveOutputStream.html) from [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) library you can create a .tar.lzma file, an archive readable by 7-zip and many other archiver programs that uses LZMA compression.  It will also give you solid compression, which it sounds like is what you want if the PDF files are very similar.

The java lzma SDK you are using will probably work just as well as LZMA-java, I only have experience with LZMA-java.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Java port of 7zip on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/). I know it exist but not much more.

Answer (score 0):

it is more a question than an answer:

processing a pdf with 7zip I only get the correct number of pages, but all are empty.....

My goal is a password proteced stick with important documents of all kinds. As I did not get an answer one the portableapps forum I now use bitlocker on windows 8.1.